# Will Url rewrite with htaccess make website discovered by search engine?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

Okay this might be little off from programming. But if let's say that I have a website that its url is rewritten from

> www.example.com?index.php?id=1&cat=category&title=My-Title

to

> www.example.com/1/category/My-Title

will it be able to be searched as the second Url by search engines? For example, if I type "category my-title" Google will show

> www.example.com/1/**category**/***My-Title***

instead of

> www.example.com?index.php?id=1&cat=**category**&title=**My-Title**

Or is there any necessary code need to be added to htaccess file?

Comment: Just make sure you don't have any links pointing to `www.example.com?index.php?id=1&cat=category&title=My-Title` and it will work without any problems.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite and 301 redirect to the new page, but also don't forget to ad the canonical link to the head. In your case:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/1/category/My-Title" />
```

Also, I advise against using capital letters in urls.

Comment: Hey thanks for the canonical link tips. However I can't get the href link I want using `$_GET['id']` and/or `$_GET['title']`. Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search engine results **Google actually recommends** using server side 301 (Moved Permanently) redirects.

You can use the same technique (server side 301 redirects) if you have multiple URLs to the same page. Then you use the redirect to the default page.

So in your case `www.example.com/1/category/My-Title` will be the URL used by Google search engine.

Please have a look at [Google Webmaster Tools - 301 redirects](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) which explains redirects in greater details.

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

That is fine. The new URL is the real URL of this page

Comment: @jeroen & In God | Trust: Oh, so as long as my href didnt point to **..id=1&cat=category..** it should work fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user2002495 having that pointing as well will just list them both which you dont want. So just keep all you urls the same